# How to set the table width equal to the page width

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a below html code in my aspx page. I want to set the table width to 100% and it doesn't seems to work. Am I doing wrong anywhere?

```
<table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
        <td height="15">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                   //page menus are being placed here
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also I have a grid below this table. The `gridview` stretches to right, but this table doesn't equally come with the `gridview`.

Comment: Is there anything around the table that limits its size?

Comment: No there is nothing around the table.

Comment: Have you tried putting "width" on the TD?

Comment: add `cellspacing="0"` and `cellpadding="0"` to table

Comment: Also, when I have these issues, I find it easier to see what is happening by temporarily putting "border: thin solid <color>" on table, tr, td elements...

Comment: Do you have the final page online to see what's actually rendered ?

Comment: can you simulate it in JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a proper html document:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
*{margin:0;padding:0;}//clear default browser margin & padding from all elements
html,body{width:100%;position:relative;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
        <td height="15">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                   //page menus are being placed here
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

The  tag does not have any CSS rules automatically applied to it. But the  tag has default margins on all browsers, so all you need to do is shave them off by using the following CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Click the <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button below to check it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; border:1px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <td height="15">
      <div id="menu">
        <ul>
          //page menus are being placed here
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```